# Drupal 7 "Panel Nodes" Content Pane Contextual Filter

Tags: 7, panels, views

Does anyone know how to set up a taxonomy-based contextual filter (argument) for a Views Content Pane that is going to be displayed in a "Panel Node" (from the "Panel Node" module that comes with Panels) tagged with the same taxonomy term?

I think I am missing something about how "Panel Nodes" works. I don't get the option for a term ID unless I add a "Relationship" to the taxonomy field in Views. Then I can set the Contextual Filter to the term ID, but it does not work consistently. If I set the "Argument Input" for the pane to "From Context", it works in Views preview with an argument, but it's blank on the actual Panel Node (if the Pane even shows up to be added). If I set it to anything other than "No Argument", it doesn't work at all.

When I use an argument to preview the Content Pane in Views, it works as it should. But on the "Panel Node" page, it's blank. I don't think the argument is making it to the pane.

Some background: 
"Panel Nodes" is a module that comes with Panels and it creates this Panel-ified content type, but I'm finding very little documentation on how to use it. Panel Nodes are not in Page Manager and so you cannot set a context for them there.

I have a client that could use Panels in their Drupal 7 site just for one particular kind of content type. For this particular use case, the the "Panel Nodes" way of generating the content is the most intuitive for the client (enter a title, body, an image into a node add form, and then click on the Panels Layout and Panels Content tabs right from the node form; I believe this is a similar model to the way http://drupal.org/project/panelizer is supposed to work).

Comment: This could be me being tired, but I don't understand what you are asking. Could it be re-phrased as: "In a Panel Node, I want to display a list of other nodes, with the same term."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I urge you **not** to use Panel Nodes. Panel Nodes are being deprecated in favor of [Panelizer](http://drupal.org/project/panelizer). The largest hurdle to getting rid of them is that I need to complete the [upgrade path](http://drupal.org/node/1353542). I suggest that you

1. Move to Panelizer, following the upgrade path issue if you already have Panel Nodes.
2. If necessary, repost a new question with regard to Panelizer.

Comment: Thanks Letharion. My bad I should have circled back and answered this question. Merlinofchaos and/or you told me in the issue queues that Panel Nodes was being deprecated. So I ditched it and built my client's feature with Panelizer. That worked well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where is it mentioned that Panel Nodes are being depreciated? I've just started on a project that uses those extensively and the thought they're being depreciated in favour of Panelizer is probably pretty worrisome...

Comment: Officially, they're not deprecated until there is an upgrade path, so technically they are not, _yet_. However, no one is interested in supporting PN any more. Questions aren't really being answered, bugs are unlikely to be fixed unless they are truly critical. Building with PN is fine if you are willing to fix any problems yourself, but then again, if you are _starting_, why not just use Panelizer instead?