# Pulling content from other nodes into a Panel Node

Tags: 7, panels, nodes, entities

I'm using Panel Nodes* to let users create content with varying layouts. I'm wanting to display another node in one of the panels.

When I create the Panel Node and go to create a new Content pane, I click Entity then Rendered Node. However, the Entity dropdown only lists "This node". If I click Node instead and then try to insert a Node Content panel content type, the Node dropdown is still "This node". What am I missing?

I've tried using [EntityReference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to associate a Panels node with the other content type, but it doesn't increase the options available to me.

**Any idea how I'd render a node from another content type in a Panel Nodes Panel?**

Thanks!

`*`Yes, [I know I should use Panelizer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/drupal-7-panel-nodes-content-pane-contextual-filter), but I'm wanting to know if there's a way to do this without converting everything I've done thus far to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add an Object to your Panel Pane, you will find in the left column the option to add an "Existing node", choosing this, you can add a node id of the content you want to add.

If you want to dynamically provide different nodes provided by the user input on the node form using a node reference field, you need to add a context to the panel by using this reference field and then the referenced node will also be available.

Comment: Oh. Wow. I totally just thought that was like a "legend" or something. TODAY'S AWARD FOR TOTALLY MISSING THE OBVIOUS GOES TO...! Thanks a whole lot, that's really helpful!